# Empty item at end of .each loop because of rails cycle method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, cycle, link-to

I have this list that should show all activities inside a category, and it sort of works but the last element that is displayed is strange. There are 4 activities in the DB for this particular category and at the end of the list I'm getting an item `/categories/1/activities`

```
%table.catlist
  - @category.activities.each do |activity|
    %tr{:class => cycle('one','two')}
      %td= link_to activity.name, [@category, activity]
      %td &nbsp;
```

I also tried:

```
link_to activity.name, category_activity_path(:category_id => @category.id, :id => activity.id)
```

But that's not working at all, and giving me this error:

```
No route matches {:category_id=>1, :action=>"show", :controller=>"activities", :id=>nil}
```

The routes are nested like this:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :activities do
      resources :records
    end
  end
```

It's actually showing everything right, but it closes the list with this strange element which is basically the activity path, but without an id.

## EDIT

I think this is happening because of the `cycle` method that is supposed to switch between CSS classes. Any ideas how the empty row can be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably building a new activity in your controller which is included in the list of activities for `@category`.  If you have the following code in your controller,

```
@activity = @category.activities.build
```

try changing it to

```
@activity = Activity.new category_id: @category.id
```

or add a check in the view to only show persisted activities.

```
- @category.activities.each do |activity|
  - next if activity.new_record?
  %tr{:class => cycle('one','two')}
    %td= link_to activity.name, [@category, activity]
    %td &nbsp;
```

Comment: I don't think that's it, basically the only thing I have in my controller is `@category = Category.find(params[:id])` and a format_to block

Comment: can you try the last code?  i'm pretty sure that you have an activity that is a new record which is why you get the error.

Comment: That did fix it. Strange though, I really can't see where the new record is being created